# what is a generic term for any work to be marked by teacher

Tags: word-choice

As the title mentions: what is generic term for any work to be marked by teacher (exam, test, assignment, report) ?

Comment: I would call it an *assignment*, as you did.

Comment: Graded work is any exam, test, assignment, report marked by a teacher, or their assistant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Classwork* or *homework* were the two categories used when I was at school. You could also add *exercise* to your list of more general words.

*Exams* and *Tests* tend to be under set conditions, usually timed and invigilated in some way. Assignments and reports are usually homework, because you are *assigned* to go away and *report* back on what you have learned.

edit: as @Geobits pointed out, a good general word for assessed work working towards a particular qualification is *coursework*.

Comment: Also *coursework*.

Comment: As a university teacher, I generally use *coursework* to refer to the set of courses a student must take and pass to complete a degree program or similar requirement, though neither M-W nor OED nor MS-Word appears to recognize the word at all. For the meaning here in question I favor *schoolwork* or *academic work* or just *work* or even (borrowing from lawyering, in the context of syllabus language insisting that the stuff in question be authentically the student's own) *academic work product.*

Comment: @BrianDonovan Yes, I've seen it used for the work done for a single class and in the broader sense you mentioned. I typically see it used in the first sense more in lower grades, such as high/secondary-school work.